# JAVA Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, cucumber-serenity

Hello I am using Java/selenium for test automation and starting from today I am having this error while using Edge. Everything was working just fine.
It started with Chrome 4 weeks ago then I used -Dchrome.switches="--remote-allow-origins=*" to solve it.
But now with Edge I have no idea how to solve it.

I would really appreciate your help, thank you !

> Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully.
> avr. 11, 2023 5:59:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFOS: Detected dialect: W3C
> avr. 11, 2023 5:59:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
> AVERTISSEMENT: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden

```
webdriver.driver=Edge
serenity.keep.unscaled.screenshots = true
serenity.project.name = Socle Automate Cucumber
serenity.use.unique.browser = false
serenity.batch.count=1
serenity.batch.number=1
webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait 10000
serenity.console.colors = true
webdriver.autodownload=true
```

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved my issue with chrome and edge, maybe you can do similar approach.if web driver setup class
option.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");("--remote-allow-origins=*");

```
        "Chrome":
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("allow-running-insecure-content");
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            // in Chrome
            options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          
       "Edge":
            EdgeOptions option = new EdgeOptions();
            option.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
            // in Edge
            option.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            webDriver = new EdgeDriver(option);
```